# Centos 6-7 install argument for GUID Partition Table

Tags: linux, centos

From here http://www.tecmint.com/centos-7-installation/ item 11

> NOTE:For those users, who have hard-disks more than 2TB in size, the
>   installer automatically will convert partition table to GPT, but if
>   you wish to use GPT table on smaller disks than 2TB, then you should
>   use the argument inst.gpt to the installer boot command line in order
>   to change the default behaviour.

Could anyone explain in detaila how to add inst.gpt argument and when. Let's suppose I switched on computer and inserted Centos DVD. What's next?

Comment: I can't tell you exactly the steps now, but this is an intaller option. Once you booted on your DVD, the first menu display something like "Install CentOS" and "Press TAB for full options". So press TAB and I guess you will have a `boot:` prompt. Here you'd have to type `linux inst.gpt` to start the installed as specified. Sorry, I don't have a CentOS to test right know. Hope it helps somehow...

Comment: @apaul Anyway thank you. At least I'll start from this point.